# Python: How do you scrape daily data from dynamic web using Python?

Tags: python, web-scraping

The following code works but stops after 29th of Feb. The website returns "you have entered an invalid date. Please re-enter your search", which necessitate clicking on "OK". How do I get around this?

```
country_search("United States")
time.sleep(2)
date_select = Select(driver.find_element_by_name("dr")) 
date_select.select_by_visible_text("Enter date range...") #All Dates
select_economic_news()
#btnModifySearch
for month in range(1,9):
for day in range(1,32):
    try:
    
        set_from_month(month)
        set_from_date(day)
        set_from_year("2020")
        set_to_month(month)
        set_to_date(day)
        set_to_year("2020")
                
        time.sleep(5)
        #select_economic_news()
        time.sleep(5)
        search_now()
        time.sleep(8)                
                
        export_csv()
        modify_search()
        
        time.sleep(5)        
        #country_remove()
    except ElementClickInterceptedException:
        break
```

logout()

Comment: It's hard to give any specific advice without seeing the data being scraped. Is the daily data on the same page as the monthly data and we just need to find a pattern or are we scraping for unique urls to get access to that data and then finding a pattern?

Comment: that's the issue, to download data, I have to select "enter date range", which only returns monthly data. The only way to get daily data from this specific platform is to enter specific date for each day of each month for the period jan-2020-august 2020. wouldn't we need a loop for this?

Comment: I've provided a possible loop if these are the only methods you have at your disposal. If you're manually scraping the HTML then we would benefit from seeing what you're working with the help identify patterns for looping.

Comment: Thank you!! so far the code works but stops end of february 29th (shorter month), how do I get it to ignore the error? Given that the error generate a pop-up box with a "Please re-enter your search" message, I am supposed to account for this as well? I am unable to inspect the pop-up box, hence I don't see how to include this part into the code.

Answer (score 0):

If you can only use the methods featured in the initial post then I would try something like:

```
set_from_year('2020')
set_to_year('2020')
for month in range(1, 9):
    # 1 to 9 for Jan to Aug
    month_str = '0' + str(month)
    set_from_month(month_str)
    set_to_month(month_str)
    for day in range(1, 32):
        # Assuming an error is thrown for invalid days
        try:
            # Store data as needed
        except Exception as e:
            # print(e) to learn from error if needed
            pass
```

There is a lot more that goes into this if it turns out that you're writing these methods yourself and need to loop through HTML and find a pattern for daily data.

Answer (score 0):

I believe you want to dynamically obtain the number of days in a month, so that you can loop over that number to get data for each date. You can do this as follows:

```
from datetime import datetime
currentDay = datetime.today()
# You can set the currentDay using this if you want the data till the current date or 
# whenever your scheduler runs the job.


# Now you need to get the number of days in each month from the chosen date, you can 
# have the corresponding function like getStartMonth() in your program which will 
# return the starting month.  
from calendar import monthrange
daysPerMonth = {}
year = currentDay.year #TODO : change this to getStartYear()
startMonth = 3 # TODO : Implement getStartMonth() in your code.
for month in range(startMonth, currentDay.month+1):
    # monthrange returns (weekday,number of days in that month)
    daysPerMonth[month] = monthrange(year, month)[1]

for month in daysPerMonth.items(): 
    print(month[0], '-',month[1])
```

This will output something like this(*Number of days in a month from - March 2020 till August 2020*):

```
3 - 31
4 - 30
5 - 31
6 - 30
7 - 31
8 - 31
```

And then you can run a loop for number of days while referring the range from the dict that you've obtained.
NOTE : In the function where you're running the loop to get data for each date add one if condition to check if it's the last day of the year and modify the year accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe You can use these function to get count days of month:

```
import datetime


def get_month_days_count(year: int, month: int) -> int:
    date = datetime.datetime(year, month, 1)
    while (date + datetime.timedelta(days=1)).month == month:
        date = date + datetime.timedelta(days=1)
    return date.day
```